# OAuth2 Implemenation with Restsharp.Portable

Tags: xamarin.forms, restsharp

I'm doing an application for android, iOS and Windows Phone using Xamarin.forms.
I need to implement login with most common social for all platforms and I have found on web Restsharp.Portable.
I'm having trouble to understand how to use the library (it was correctly imported) for OAuth2 request.
Does anyone have any example or guide that could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with restsharp.portable due to the lack of documentation. 
Instead I used the redirect URL as a way of getting the code generated after the user gives permission needed to request the access token.

I gave the browser the correct adddress for the login/permission screen and for the Redirect I set to a made up address (http://madeupaddress.com) and on the Navigating event of the browser checked if the url started with my made up address, if so, I cancel navigation, closed the browser and take the token from the URI.Query parameters found in the navigating event parameters (or named differently depending on control/platform). I thenapply for the access token using the code via Microsoft HTTP Client.
This was for Windows Phone 8.1.

Thanks go to [Vittorio Bertocci](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/16/a-sample-windows-phone-8-app-getting-tokens-from-windows-azure-ad-and-adfs/#comment-156665)

I ended up using Microsoft Httpclient for the access token.

Comment: Thank you! I am following your way. It's hard to find documentation for Restsharp.

Comment: Its quite a handy way for all oauth2 where a browser is needed. Helps me authenticate my own user so I can use dropbox for my app storage.